# Right Alt + letter 'a' doesn't work

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, ansi, alt

Good morning to all!

I'm having a problem with my new keyboard and I'm going to share it here to see if someone can help me.
I am from Spain and I have always used national ISO keyboards but as I am a software programmer I decided to take the leap to an American ANSI keyboard because of the good reputation they have for these tasks. In addition, I read that with the right Alt you can access the characters I use in my language without much complication, but here came the problems.

I found a keyboard that mapped all the accents and the special key n with the symbol ~ above 'ñ' simply, as I explained before, it is to press right Alt and the corresponding key, this is done as a substitute for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> the famous deadkey layout. And indeed it works with all keys except 'a': 'éíóúñ'.

I've tried to find out why the error, at first I thought it would be hardware because in a web test the keyboard is not able to show me the two keys pressed at the same time although it detects that I press the 'a' when I press it holding down the right Alt, with any other combination of buttons works perfectly and only with right Alt and the combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> is when it does not work so I have some hope that it is a software issue, maybe drivers or firmware? My keyboard is DREVO Gramr V2 TE.

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you maybe have other software running on your system that captures `AltGr+a`? E.g. Keepass is known to set `AltGr+a` as a global hotkey for auto-typing.

Comment: Perfect! I was running keepass with that option. I set off and works like a charm! Thank you so much!!